# Do I have to learn all of the insults and comebacks to be able to advance in The Secret of Monkey Island?

Tags: the-secret-of-monkey-island

When I get to the insult sword-fighting stage of The Secret of Monkey Island, do I have to learn every single insult and comeback in order to beat the Sword Master?

Comment: You fight like a dairy farmer.

Comment: How appropriate...

Comment: "You just don't have what it takes"

Comment: I am rubber, you are glue...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thankfully no, you don't have to learn them all. It is a bit tedious to get all the comebacks since some of the uncommon ones take a while to find.

To beat the Sword Master you only need to do comeback for a subset of all the insults, i.e. [some of the Sword Master's insults have multiple comebacks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42718/11742). You can go to the Sword Master earlier but it requires some luck.

Comment: Thankfully? They were funny enough to learn all IMHO

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, the comebacks are all funny; but I wish it was equally funny to aquire them in the game. Only about 2-3 pirates respawn at a time, some more frequent than others, and chances are it'll take a long while to get the last ones.

Comment: In fact, [some of the Sword Master's insults have multiple valid comebacks](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42718/11742), so even if you haven't learnt the "correct" response to an insult, you might be able to use an alternate one.

Answer (score 9):

No, you can fight the sword master without knowing all the comebacks. It's all a matter of luck which insults she throws at you.

Answer (score 6):

A defeated pirate will say "Wow! You're good enough to fight the Sword Master" once you have a good proportion of answers.  I usually take this as the time I can go fight her:

[image: DairyFarmer]

If you don't know the answer to an insult from the Sword Master it isn't a real problem.  You have a small margin of error before you are defeated... and I have never been given repeated insults in one fight so its not like she will continue to chain up the same insult in one single fight.

**Update**

According to [this source](http://monkeyisland.wikia.com/wiki/Insult_Sword_Fighting) regarding insult responses:

> There are 16 in all. Once you learn 12 and win three fights with normal pirates, they will begin to say 'You're good enough to fight the Sword Master'.

Comment: IIRC every insult can only be used once in a fight, the AI keeps to that rule as well.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC no, you'll be able to beat the Sword Master once you have learned a certain quantity of insults, but you don't need all of them.